# How to roll multiple dice using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop

The following code rolls 5 dice at once but with 5 different variables. I'm trying to use a for-loop to achieve this instead. Is this logical or do I need 5 different variables for every dice?

```
function dieroll() {
          var roll= "&#x268" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + ";";
          var roll2= "&#x268" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + ";";
          var roll3= "&#x268" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + ";";
          var roll4= "&#x268" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + ";";
          var roll5= "&#x268" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + ";";
          var roll6= "&#x268" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + ";";   
    return roll + roll2 + roll3 + roll4 + roll5;
  }
```

Comment: Use an array instead of different variables. Also, you can place the RHS part in another variable, you don't want to write the same thing 6 times!

Comment: Exactly! I didn't want to repeat myself either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach could be:

```
function dieroll() {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    result.push("&#x268" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + ";");
  }
  return result;
};
```

With this definition, a call to **dieroll()** would look like:

> dieroll()
>
> > ["⚁", "⚂", "⚂", "⚂", "⚂"]

Comment: If you are returning a string each time, then there should be an array inside the `for` loop to store the returned values, don't you think so?

Comment: This worked! Thank you. Now is it possible to achieve this without the array. The commas between the items don't look good.

Comment: `return dice.join(''); `